# If I have two lines, how do I find which line is on top after an intersection?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I have two lists of points for the graph so I can plot two lines. I'm using matplotlib to find the intersections of the two lines. However, these points are not necessarily in the original list of points. What I'm trying to do is to find which is line on top and which line is on the bottom immediately after the intersection. I was thinking about using the derivative at that point what I am not sure how to do that or if there an is easier way.

```
        line1 = [30,32,40,50,31,20]
        line2 = [29,37,23,30,51,32]
        l1 = LineString(line1)
        l2 = LineString(line2)
        intersection = l1.intersection(l2)
        intersect_points = [list(p.coords)[0] for p in intersection]
```

intersect_points would give a list of the intersections between the two lists.We can see from the points that list1 and list2 intersects from 30-32 and 29-37. The actual point of intersection would be given in intersect_points. I want to know which one is on top. In this case, list 2 would be on top after the intersection.

Comment: Could you include some sample code that is representative of your two lines and your attempt so far?

Comment: This is extremely unclear.  What do you mean by on-top?  Why are you finding the intersection using matplotlib?  What does this have to do with a moving-average?

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post

Comment: from what I gather, the easiest thing would be to have the `intersection` function to also return a value indicating which one of the two sequences has a higher value (for each point of intersection). That way no indexing would be necessary

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, I think the easiest thing would be to have the `intersection` method to also return a value to flag which one of the two lines has a higher value for each point of intersection. That way no indexing would be necessary.

Note: this solutions ignores `numpy`

Here is a sample code (unoptimized and optimistic):

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.pts = list(seq)

    def intersection(self, line):
        """ returns the list of intersections.
        each element is a tuple formed by
            flag  True if the second line is on top
            x     the position of the intersection along the x axis
            y     the value of the intersection along the y axis"""

        ret = []
        pos = 0
        z = iter(zip(self.pts, line.pts))
        p, pl = next(z)
        for c, cl in z:
            denom = c - p - cl + pl
            if denom:
                numer = pl - p
                if numer:
                    x = float(numer) / float(denom)
                    y = (c - p)*x + p
                else:
                    x = 0.0
                    y = float(p)
                ret.append((cl > c, float(pos) + x, y))
            p, pl = c, cl
            pos += 1
        return ret
```

Let's try it out:

```
>>> from intersection import *
>>> a=Line([2,7,4])
>>> b=Line([5,3,6])
>>> a.intersection(b)
[(False, 0.42857142857142855, 4.142857142857142),
 (True, 1.6666666666666665, 5.0)]
```

As you can see, on the first intersection it shows the `a` line is on top, whereas on the second one line `b` is on top.

I hope it helps.

:)